# Components in layer 1 appearing above those of layer 0 when hovering the mouse above them

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlayeredpane

In this JFrame, I added a JLayeredPane of two panels.menu,a JPanel,is added at layer 0. mainPanel is the panel on the right side ,that is added at layer 1. Why when hovering the mouse over the button of the menu ,the radiobuttons on the mainPanel (layer1) appear above the menu(layer 0).
Any solutions?

Note that Menu.moreDetails is a jlabel with an imageIcon,the menu Panel opens/closes when clicking  on this jlabel.

[image]

[image]

```
public class HomePage {

  Dimension DimMax;
  JFrame homeFrame;
  CardLayout card ;
  JPanel mainPanel ;
 
static JPanel homePanel;

public void createFrame() {

    DimMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    card = new CardLayout();
    homeFrame = new JFrame();
    homePanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel= new JPanel(card);
    Menu menu = new Menu(mainPanel, card);
    JLayeredPane layer = new JLayeredPane();

    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    menu.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));

    menu.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(24, DimMax.height));
    //menu.setOpaque(true);
    mainPanel.setOpaque(false);

    mainPanel.setBounds(24, 0, DimMax.width - 24, DimMax.height);
    menu.setBounds(0, 0, 24, DimMax.height);

    layer.add(mainPanel, 1);
    layer.add(menu, 0, 0);
    
    homeFrame.add(layer);
    layer.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        boolean open = false;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getSource() == Menu.moreDetails) {
                if (open) {
                    menu.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(24, DimMax.height));
                    menu.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(24, DimMax.height));
                    menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(24, DimMax.height));
                    menu.setBounds(0, 0, 24, DimMax.height);

                    menu.revalidate();
                    open = false;
                } else {

                    menu.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(120, DimMax.height));
                    menu.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(120, DimMax.height));
                    menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, DimMax.height));
                    menu.setBounds(0, 0, 120, DimMax.height);

                    menu.revalidate();
                    HomePage.homeFrame.revalidate();
                    HomePage.homePanel.revalidate();
                    open = true;
                }

            }
        }

    });

   
    homeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    homeFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    homeFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    homeFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Swing assumes components are displayed in 2D, not 3D. So it is not easy to layout components on top of one another. For example when you move the mouse over the the frame Swing will attempt to dispatch a mouse event to the component. So it searches for a component with a MouseListener at the current mouse location. By default a JRadioButton has a MouseListner. So the mouse event get dispatched to that component and the component gets repainted on top of the menu. Maybe you can add a MouseListener to the menu panel to intercept all mouse event?

Comment: Or maybe a better design is to NOT use a JLayeredPane and instead just use a panel with a BorderLayout. So the "Menu" panel would be added to the BorderLayout.LINE_START and the "Main" panel added to the BorderLayout.CENTER. The "Menu" can then dynamically resize as required.

Comment: I used a gridbaglayout previously  to add the menu and the mainPanel, but the problem was that opening the menu(increasing its size) was pushing the mainpanel to the right.

Comment: Thank your for this note!Adding a mouse listener solved the issue.